# Error al crear FK en MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me da ese error al crear una FK, esta KEY ya existía y se elimino al actualizar la tabla y al intentar crearla me tira ese error.

Comment: Lo más probable es que cuando se eliminó la FK, se insertó algún registro que no la cumple, y por lo tanto no puedes crearla ahora sin antes eliminar los registros erróneos

Comment: el error parece mas del gestor, intenta hacerlo por comando sql desde la consola a ver si te devuelve el mismo error